# DropdownButton is not changing the value on onChanged

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

The DropdownButton is not changing the value of dropdown after another selection is made from the dropdown. Below is my code.

```
Flexible(
   child: Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
   child: DropdownButton(
      hint: Text('Select'),
      items: list_dropdown,
      onChanged: (val) {
         setState(() {
           wd = val;                          
         });
      },
      value: wd,
   )),
)
```

In the initState I'm setting the value variable

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();

   wd = 0;
}
```

while I create the variale in the global scope

```
int wd;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you create a variable in the global scope? If you want to mutate your variable called `wd` with `setState()`, you have to put it in your state class.

```
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // Here wd in my state class
  int wd = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Cat Attack"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: DropdownButton(
            value: wd,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                wd = val;
              });
            },
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text('1'),
                value: 1,
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Text('2'),
                value: 2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

You can override the value of wd in `initState()`, once you've defined in state.

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  int wd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    wd = 2;
  }
```

Keep in mind that, your "value" for DropdownButton should be set to 'null' or be one from the values list. So if you set it to 5, rather then 1, 2 or null, which are the values in my `DropdownMenuItem`'s, you will get this error:

> I/flutter (15227): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter (15227): The following assertion was thrown building App(dirty, state: _AppState#30354):
>   I/flutter (15227): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 560 pos 15: 'items == null ||
>   I/flutter (15227): items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value ==
>   I/flutter (15227): value).length == 1': is not true.